# How to put file in the document directory of my app?

Tags: xcode

maybe stupid question, but i am trying to read plist that I have in my app. That's no problem, but here is my problem. I have my plists in main bundle, but i want to update them dynamically from the web, but there is no permission to write to main bundle, so how can I put the plists to the documents directory of the app???

Or is there any possibility to overwrite them in main bundle when I download new ones from internet?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the one inside **Documents** exists at first execution of the application, otherwise copy it from the main bundle (with class `NSFileManager` you can easily do that).

Then you always work on the one in **Documents** folder, even because, as you stated, you are not allowed to modify things that reside in main bundle. They are considered read-only.

Comment: okay thanks a lot =) and when I download the new ones, then just only overwrite it=) Thanks a lot, really helped=)